# Running MongoDB Compass on Mac

Tags: mongodb

```
Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4
```

I installed the MongoDB server Community edition on my Mac without a problem (seemingly). I then installed MongoDB Compass community edition, from the MongoDB download center. The setup completed without any errors. When I try to run Compass, I get the following error message:

```
“MongoDB Compass.app” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
```

Anyone else running into this?

## Solution:

This warning is because the Compass binary isn’t notarised for macOS yet. MongoDB is working on resolving the issue. The workaround, for now, is to right click on it in the Applications folder, and select Open, you get a second warning, but this time, there's an additional button allowing you to open it.

Comment: Try to move your application into `Applications` & then re-launch it from there, In general that should solve most of these issues ! I've faced it couple of times with few other applications & it worked..

Comment: That's where I'm running it from

Comment: Then try this one : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362883/mongodb-doesnt-work-after-update-to-macos-catalina-10-15, Check out answer from @Cameron, I did that once..

Comment: I am not having a problem running the MongoDB server (see my question). What I am having a problem with, is the MongoDB Compass management dashboard

Answer (score 36):

System Preferences >> Security & Privacy >> General >> [Unlock]>> Allow apps Downloaded from >> You will find an alert specifically for MongoDB Compass
Previously there was an option to enable from "Anywhere". Now it's removed.

Comment: I wonder why over two months later this issue hasn't been addressed by the developer? IMO bypassing the OS signature and verification requirements is a bad practice.