# “MongoDB Compass” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: mongodb

When I try to install MongoDB Compass on macOS Catalina, the following occurs:

```
“MongoDB Compass” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running MongoDB Compass on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61739960/running-mongodb-compass-on-mac) Making this question as Dup

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to **System Preferences**
2. Select **Security & Privacy**
3. Select **General**
4. Select **Open Anyway** which is to the right of **"MongoDB Compass" was blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer.**
5. Select **Open** in the successive dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Installing with brew worked for me:

```
brew install --cask mongodb-compass
```