# Unable to launch MongoDB On MacOS Monterey | Error MongoDB Compass” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: mongodb, apple-m1, macos-monterey, mongodb-compass

I am unable to use MongoDb Compass on MacOS Monterey With Following Error. I tried every possible solution to resolve it.

ERROR: “MongoDB Compass” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

reinstallation of application , Restart machine , Open Anyway Option, Control + click and open from FInder. still MAc is not allowing to launch it and says

“This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information.”[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLwHb.png)

Tried following too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Bgd.png)

Did try : [“MongoDB Compass” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450414/mongodb-compass-can-t-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-so)

None of above worked.

Answer (score 0):

From [support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/apple-cant-check-app-for-malicious-software-mchleab3a043/mac)

> Apple can’t check app for malicious software
>
> Using an app that can’t be checked for malicious software might harm
> your Mac or compromise your privacy. If you’re certain that the app
> you want to use is from a trustworthy source, you can override your
> Mac security settings to open it.
>
> ```
> In the Finder on your Mac, locate the app you want to open.
>
> Don’t use Launchpad to locate the app.
>
> Control-click the app icon, then choose Open from the shortcut menu.
>
> Click Open.
>
> The app is saved as an exception to your security settings, and you can open it at any time by double-clicking it, just as you do with
> ```
>
> any registered app.

Comment: I tried that several times still getting the same pop up error that  “MongoDB Compass” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Answer (score 0):

Here's How I did it. Finally...

open New Terminal Window -> Run Following

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

then I got **

> Anywhere

** option In **system Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Open Anyway**

Then Clicked on Open and it Launched.

Note: Run following command once you open your App to save your machine from malicious Software in future.

```
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

Refrence: [How to Make Mac Allow Apps Downloaded from Anywhere 2022](https://iboysoft.com/news/allow-apps-downloaded-anywhere-mac.html#:%7E:text=This%20is%20to%20disable%20Gatekeeper,Allow%20apps%20downloaded%20from%22%20section.)